# Error in creating resources with scaffold

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scaffolding

I try to execute the following command:

```
  rails generate scaffold Micropost content:string user id:integer
```

After executing the following command the following error messages are coming:

```
 /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:296:in `to_specs': Could not find 'railties' (>= 0) among 13 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:307:in `to_spec'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:47:in `gem'
from /usr/local/bin/rails:22:in `<main>'
```

But before that I have executed another such statement to create a resource named User. This ran successfully. I am new to Rails. I have no idea about the error. Can anyone help me to fix that? Thank you.

Comment: Have you run "bundle" before scaffolding?

Comment: Are you talking about run bundle install? Yes I have executed it. Should I execute it once again?

Comment: yes I m referring to 'bundle install' . Yes, Please try it once again, then go for scaffolding.

Comment: After one scaffold statement if I execute bundle install will the resource created by earlier scaffold remain intact or I have to create them once again?

Comment: you need to do bundle install, after you will do changes in the Gemfile. and bundle install does not make any changes to your folder structure. BTW in your scaffold code rails generate scaffold Micropost content:string user id:integer, what is the user? it should be user_id:integer I guess.

Comment: Yes you are right. Ohh I need to edit Gemfile. I did not know that. I mean could you please tell me what change should I do to Gemfile.

Comment: No no.. you dont need to edit the Gemfile. I am guessing that, you have added some new gem and after that you forgot to run bundle install. But if you have not added or removed any gems from GemFile, then you need not have to run bundle install.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to run the `bundle install` command.

This command should be run after every changes you make in the file named `Gemfile` at the root of your Rails project. The `Gemfile` is the place where you'll want to declare all your applications dependencies (gems).

Please have a look [here](http://bundler.io/v1.3/gemfile.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I have met exactly the same problem with you. As is my case, I just modify the `Gemfile` and the rails outputs the approximately the same information as you described.

1. First you need to run `gem install bundler` to check whether the bundler is prepared.
2. Then run `bundle update` to update your gems
3. Finally run `bundle install` to get all gems installed

I just solved the problem after the three steps as above.